# How to configure basic authentication in WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, basic-authentication, postman, wordpress-rest-api

I want to allow WP REST API communication after authentication using postman in wordpress. But I can not find any way to configure basic authentication in WP REST API

Comment: may be this can help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762.

Comment: not very much help ful